# Dynamics 365 popup window with input

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, xrm

I would like to popup a window with two questions and a button on button click I would like to pass the answers to an action and execute it.

So I created an action with 3 arguments:
two arguments are my questions from type Boolean and third is an output argument: [Action_TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0tza.png)

From this point I'm a little bit clueless of what I need to do. Basically I want to popup a window [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcwD.png) with two Boolean questions and button which will pass the answers to the action and will execute the action.

Comment: You haven't included the important information question. What is the name of your `action` and what code are you using to execute the action

Answer (score 3):

1. You can basically design a HTML form in Web resource with textbox/radio button controls & a `submit` button
2. [Open this web resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource) on your need something like ribbon button click using `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource(webResourceName,windowOptions,data)`
3. After data entry on popup form, on click of `submit` button [call the action](https://debajmecrm.com/2018/02/02/dynamics-version-9-0-execute-custom-action-with-all-parameter-types-in-dynamics-crm-version-9-0/) using `Xrm.WebApi.online.execute`

Comment: I'm stuck in the second stage:

This is my web resource:
var windowOptions = { openInNewWindow: true, height: 400, width: 400 }
Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource("new_html_test",windowOptions);

I need the window to popup when I change the "Gender" field: https://ibb.co/nCNTq8

This is the current problems:
The window pops up when the form loads.

When I try to change the "Gender" field I get an error: https://ibb.co/i9spxo

Comment: @user3617337 I assume the code you shared in above comment is residing inside a function of new_new js library webresource, while registering in onchange event give that function name instead of Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource in 1st screenshot..